# List attachments times out for messages with attachments, returns quickly otherwise

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to write a nodejs service to retrieve email attachments using Microsoft's graph api.

I am able to use my setup to retrieve inbox messages, so I am pretty sure the necessary permissions and oauth token have been obtained.  But for clarity's sake,  I am using client_credentials, and have this in Azure for the service:

[image: permissions]

When I request attachments from a message with 0 attachments, the request returns quickly with an empty array (as expected).

When I send a message id for a message with an attachment, the request times out.  I have set the timeout as high as 30 seconds.  The attachment in question is ~20KB, so size shouldn't be an issue.

What am I missing?

```
const baseUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/${config.graphClientVersion}/`
const attachmentsUrl = (user, messageId) => `${baseUrl}users/${user}/messages/${messageId}/attachments`

const getAttachments = async (user, mailMessageId) => {
    try {
        const result = await client
            .api(attachmentsUrl(user, mailMessageId))
            .get()

        console.log(`Graph request returned: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

//spec
it('can get attachments from emails', async () => {
    const emails = (await graph.getEmail('redacted@something.com')).value
    const result = await graph.getAttachments('redacted@something.com', emails[0].id)
    expect(result).to.exist
}).timeout(10000)
```

Comment: maybe try ```const emails = await graph.getEmail('redacted@something.com').value``` ? probably u don`t need use brackets

Comment: The parenthesis are definitely needed.  Without them the code would be attempting to read value from the Promise instead of the promise result.

Comment: Are you able to list attachments using Graph Explorer?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur With the Graph Explorer test account, yes. Unfortunately, my account hasn't been migrated yet, and is still some months away from being migrated.  I can't sign in to Graph Explorer with our service account (Okta permissions).  I reached out to our corporate IT to get the service account setup properly in Okta and will check back with any info that uncovers.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  I got an account to use from our IT.  It is able to list attachments in Graph Explorer.  My code to get email works.  I took the attachment list url from the Graph Explorer UI and hardcoded it as the parameter to the attachments api call and it still times out.  The mailbox has only 4 message, one with a 20KB attachment.  Any more ideas? <crosses fingers>

Comment: I've edited the tags in hopes it will get the right folk's attention. I can't think of a reason why fetching the messages would work but attachments times out.  I've actually never seen a Graph call time out before, it always returns a result or an error relatively quickly.